# Loop in pd.DataFrame(columns = X) where X is variable

Tags: python, pandas

So I've written a program that reads from a monthly released Excel file and converts it all into nice numpy arrays. In order to write this into an Excel file, I have to convert the numpy arrays back into DataFrames. The problem is that the "columns = " argument only takes in the names of each column, but every month, another month gets added on.

Any help is much appreciated.
Code is:

```
fundsdf = pd.DataFrame(funds[1:], columns = ???)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was literally just to write `columns = funds[0]`, so the code would be

```
fundsdf = pd.DataFrame(funds[1:], columns = funds[0])
```